# Mac mini can't mount NFS shares anymore

Tags: nfs, macos

It's impossible to mount NFS shares anymore on a Mac mini M1. It was working fine last week. There have been no changes in the network at this point.

Couple of months ago I followed this [guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-nfs-mount-command-tutorial/) to mount the NFS shares and it worked fine until a couple of days ago.

The NFS share is hosted by a Synology server and it can be listed on the Mac:

```
sh-3.2# showmount -e 10.0.0.254
Exports list on 10.0.0.254:
/volume1/Database                   *
```

But when I try to mount the system, there is an error:

```
sh-3.2# mount -o rw -t nfs 10.0.0.254:/Database /private/nfs/database
mount_nfs: can't mount /Database from 10.0.0.254 onto /private/nfs/database: Permission denied
mount: /private/nfs/database failed with 13
```

I also tried with the `-o resvport` option but that has the same result.

From a Linux system there is no issue at all mounting the same NFS share. Enabling/disabling the firewall on the Mac has no effect.

The same folder is also shared as Samba and it can be accessed using Finder. It shows a eject icon and when I press this icon it's still not possible to mount the NFS share.

OS version is Sonoma 14.0.

Any ideas what the problem could be and  how to solve it?

Comment: What are the permissions and ownerships on the `/private/nfs/database`, `/private/nfs`, and `/private` directories?  Did you ever get it to mount properly with the _very recent_ release of Sonoma?

Comment: ... and does the NFS _server_ log anything when you fail to mount?

Answer (score 0):

Well, another hour wasted. Turned out the Synology NAS was a bit confused and a reboot solved this issue. Assumed nothing was wrong with the NAS because it could be mounted on a Linux system.